# App with identity crashes at startup on Ubuntu server 20.04LTS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I have An application crash while deploying my MVC web application on the server.
It works fine on my local visual studio but crashes when started on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The error is that it doesn't start while it was starting before I added the Identity module ...
sudo systemctl stop myapp.service

```
● myapp .service - myapp app
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapp .service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-01-11 11:54:21 UTC; 4s ago
Process: 17943 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myapp .be/net5.0/myapp .be.dll (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Main PID: 17943 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

I suspect Identity manager to crash. While it works fine when on hosted on my visual studio windows dev environment
The most annoying its that it doesn't crashes it's not even launching showing no error...

**My startup.cs  file.**

```
using mysite.com.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth;

namespace mysite.com
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    //clean this latter know how to implement user secrets.json
                    options.ClientId = "xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxx";
                })
                .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
                {
                    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
                })
                ;
            string mySqlConnectionStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
 
            services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(mySqlConnectionStr, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mySqlConnectionStr)));
            services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

 
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**
Still investigating but I from what I saw on github Etc... Identity might be broken on Linux... So I switched to Windows server and everything works ...

Answer (score 2):

You can run your project with the command below in the terminal

```
dotnet run
```

if your project is published, you can use the command below in the terminal

```
dotnet YourProject.dll
```

I think you can use Nginx reverse proxy for your .net core project in Linux server

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

for more information about `Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-nginx

Comment: Thanks for you answer I maybe was not specific enough. everything worked perfectly until I added Identity module. So NGINX reverse proxy worked and .NET5 as well. IT's just when  add the Identity. Whether from the menu or scaffold ed it crashes miserably. I think it is trully some configuration or packages crashes coming from the identity module.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, How I can check your problem directly?

Comment: I truly Appreciate your help, I'll try to reproduce the problem. And send you a trace of the system logs. To see the crashes info's in more details. If you manage to create a sample .net5 mvc project with identity working on Linux Ubuntu server 20.04LTS I would be very interested to know how you have proceed. Maybe I did a configuration mistake at some point.

Comment: Your Welcome, I will definitely create a project inside Ubuntu and I will inform you of the result